# Delete all documents in a collection with Springdata mongo Query

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I want to implement a delete method which deletes all the documents in a collection. I am using mongo db with Spring Data.This could be done using db.myCollection.remove({}) in Mongo shell. But I want to write a method in my data access layer to do this.I am not using MongodbTemplate in my Dao class. I want to know how can I do this with Query.

```
Query query = new Query();
```

Could anybody please tell me how can I do it.

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about `Query` class imported? Is it from `org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository` or `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query` package?

Comment: are you using mongoTemplate ?

Answer (score 19):

You can use [`MongoTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html) directly

```java
mongoTemplate.remove(new Query(), collectionName);
```

Comment: The only correct answer here

Answer (score 9):

Use MongoRepository's [`deleteAll()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/support/SimpleMongoRepository.html#deleteAll--). Utilizes mongoTemplate behind the scene to call the [`remove`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html#remove-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query-java.lang.Class-) method.

From calling method `someRepository.deleteAll()`

Drop collection may be efficient as other answer has noted. For that you will need to use MongoTemplate directly and call [`dropCollection`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html#dropCollection-java.lang.String-) with entity class or collection name.

Comment: According to my requirement, I cannot drop the collection. I need to keep the collection. So I need a way to delete entire documents in the collection without dropping the collection.

Comment: Sure use deleteAll the first option

Comment: If you use deleteAll() it could not delete the collection and schema. It only deletes the documents. if any change in scheme does not affect the new schema.

Answer (score 9):

You can drop the collection and create it again:

```
mongoTemplate.dropCollection("collectionName");
mongoTemplate.createCollection("collectionName");
```

Comment: Hi, this is a nice solution! But keep in mind that when you drop a collection, you also delete the indexes.

Answer (score 7):

You'd better drop the entire collection (if possible) than deleting all documents. For performance and allocation sake.

You can try something such as:

```
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017));
    MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
    MongoCollection collection = db.getCollection("test_collection");
    collection.drop();
```

If you do want to delete all (I think), instead of:

```
collection.drop();
```

use:

```
Bson filter = new Document();
collection.deleteMany(filter);
```

`Query` is part of spring-data-mongodb, if you can't use a `MongoTemplate`, probably `Query` is irrelevant as well.

Comment: According to my requirement, I cannot drop the collection. I need to keep the collection. So I need a way to delete entire documents in the collection without dropping the collection.

Answer (score 1):

If you have considerable changes in schema, better is to drop the collection.
`MongoTemplate.dropCollection(collectionName)`.
But the requirement is to delete all documents you have use
`MongoTemplate.remove(new Query(), collectionName)`or
`CrudRepository.deleteAll()`

Answer (score 0):

If all collections are to be deleted, this could also be done:

```
mongoTemplate.collectionNames
        .forEach { mongoTemplate.dropCollection(it) }
```

Comment: This might lead to issues if there are indices defined on the collection. Those might not get recreated automatically again e.g. when using annotations and Spring Data.

Comment: OP is using spring mongoTemplate with Java