# How to dump the current state of the mongodatabase in SpringBoot/Java code?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, restore, dump

How can we delete the entire database from the code and not the commands??

For example, model class `testapi`:

```
public class testapi {
    @Id
    private int id;
    
    private String status;
    private ArrayList<SpotsStatus> cam_reports;
    private long date;
    
    // Constructors
    
    
    public testapi(int id, String status, ArrayList<SpotsStatus> cam_reports, long date) {
        this.id = id;
        this.status = status;
        this.cam_reports = cam_reports;
        this.date = date;
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    
    public ArrayList<SpotsStatus> getCam_reports() {
        return cam_reports;
    }
    
    public void setCam_reports(ArrayList<SpotsStatus> cam_reports) {
        this.cam_reports = cam_reports;
    }
    
    public long getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    
    public void setDate(long date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

This is my model class; my repository is:

```
public interface testRepository extends MongoRepository <testapi, Integer> {
    
}
```

In my controller, I have to write code to dump the database, restore a database and to delete the database.

My controller class is:

```
@Rest Controller
    @Request Mapping("/testapi")
        
    public class testapiController {
        
        @Autowired
        private testRepository repo;
            
        @Request Mapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public List<testapi> getAllspots() {
            return repo.findAll();
```

How can I dump? What should be the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the solutions discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49028572/delete-all-documents-in-a-collection-with-springdata-mongo-query):

Use [MongoRepository's](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html) deleteAll() for remove all data: `testRepository.deleteAll()`

Use [MongoRepository's](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html) dropCollection() and createCollection() for re-creating the whole collection:

```
testRepository.dropCollection(testapi.class);
testRepository.createCollection(testapi.class);
```

Comment: You could run this on startup of your Spring Boot App like described here: https://www.baeldung.com/running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring

Comment: I want to dump a database and not a collection

Comment: a [database dumb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_dump) is possible with [different tooling](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/) but not direct from your repositories.